Brushed Metal Texture from Material Library VX Renders Black in GPU Mode
I use brushed metal from [Material Library VX][1]. However, during GPU cycle rendering, my object appears black. Conversely, when utilizing the CPU, it adopts a chromesteel appearance, albeit lacking the desired level of shininess. Why is that?


Not enough details! Please include images of what you are seeing, the material nodes, and the settings you are using. A blend file demonstrating the problem would also be useful but please pack any images before sharing it via https://blend-exchange.com/.

Hi, sonic, I second @JohnEason 's comment. This could be a hardware / configuration problem.. we need a representative file to see if we can reproduce it. If it is not a user-setting, I'm afraid we can't help, here. Without a share, this post is vulnerable to closure as 'needing more detail'.

Ok I have upload an example file for that
